# wget: Not able to get a folder from ftp server using wget

Tags: linux, ftp, ubuntu-16.04, file-sharing, wget

I need to download an FTP package through linux, but it is not proceeding after this.

```
wget -r --no-passive-ftp --no-parent ftp://ftp.geology.wisc.edu/thurber
--2019-01-16 21:06:50--  ftp://ftp.geology.wisc.edu/thurber
           => ‘ftp.geology.wisc.edu/.listing’
Resolving ftp.geology.wisc.edu (ftp.geology.wisc.edu)... 144.92.206.97
Connecting to ftp.geology.wisc.edu (ftp.geology.wisc.edu)|144.92.206.97|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD not needed.
==> PORT ... done.    ==> LIST ... 
Error in server response, closing control connection.
Retrying.
```

When I am doing it with FileZilla, a similar problem is there. It cannot list the directories using both active and passive modes-
This is with passive mode-

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.geology.wisc.edu
Status: Connecting to 144.92.206.97:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (144,92,206,97,188,14).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

This is with active mode-

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.geology.wisc.edu
Status: Connecting to 144.92.206.97:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PORT 10,0,21,8,164,149
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: Why have you selected the `--no-passive-ftp` option?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I cannot speak for the OP. But when I run the same command without `--no-passive-ftp` it fails with `Cannot initiate PASV transfer.`

Comment: Exactly @kasperd. Same case with me.